Quad structured mesh with Gmsh using transfinite option starting from an stl file
I'm using GMSH through Python API to create a structured quadrangular mesh to perform FEM analysis of an ascending aorta for my master thesis. I have definied, on the surface of my geometry, circumferential and longitudinal splines that follow the shape of the vessel and I have imposed for these curves the transfinite option. I start from the stl file and I apply the frontal-Delaunay per quad (algorithm 8), Blossom recombination (algorithm 3) and the algorithm 11 for the quasi-structured grid.
When I remesh using "transfinite" applied to these splines, the grid improves, but it actually doesn't follow the splines, I don't have nodes on these lines as expected. It seems that the splines help to orient the grid but the result is not the one I would like to have.
This is what I've got:
enter image description here
Perhaps the "transfinite" option is not working properly because I didn't create the geometry from scratch using CAD, but instead, I started from an STL file? Do you have any suggestions for creating a structured quad mesh for my geometry? Any advice would be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to apply transfinite technique you need to set both edges and surfaces as transfinite. So, possibly you also need to divide you surface object into quad-like patches.
